# background image AND navigation bar border problems

Tags: html, css

I'm VERY new to programming and am probably using a totally old way to program my site, but so far it's been frustrating at times, but has worked for me.
Now I have 2 problems that I can't seem to fix
First: background images.  I've been checking it using Chrome, but when I open the page in IE, my background is not showing up.  I've checked the syntax (some sites seem to indicate that I needed to add spaces) and I don't see where I've got a problem.  I also tried saving the image as a png instead of jpg and that didn't work.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
body {
    background-image: url('images/backrings.jpg'), url('images/backrings2.jpg');
    background-position: left top, right top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Second: I'm getting a blue border around my footer navigation bar - I don't know why and have tried everything that I can think of to get rid of it.

Here's what the code for that looks like:

```
#footermenu ul {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    text-align: right;
    border: none 0px;

}

#footermenu ul li {
    display: inline;

}

#footermenu ul li a {
    font-family:verdana;
    font-style:normal;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color:83AFC7;
}
<div id="footermenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="first"><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>

    </ul>
    </div>
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Please reproduce this issue on your own http://www.jsfiddle.net and give us the link so we can take a deeper look.

Comment: What version of IE are you referring to? Pre IE9, CSS3 didn't support multiple backgrounds. (See http://caniuse.com/multibackgrounds)

Comment: Also, regarding the blue border, which element has the blue border? (Like Itay says, a jsfiddle or link would help)... try some `border:0;`s in various locations to see if they kill it?